# Inserting into One Field Select statement Results

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle databases.  I have an sql table `PS_Z_STAGE_TEST_JE` that has three fields (`EMPLID`, `LAST_NAME`, `FIRST_NAME`).

I am trying to do a `select` statement that will pull many EMPLIDs from sql table:`ps_vc_plan_mem` and insert them into the `EMPLID` column while leaving the other two fields (`LAST_NAME` and `FIRST_NAME`) `null`.

Below is my SQL but it will say

> Cannot insert null Value into `LAST_NAME`

when I try to run it.

```
INSERT INTO sysadm.PS_Z_STAGE_TEST_JE (EMPLID) 
    SELECT DISTINCT(emplid) 
    FROM ps_vc_plan_mem 
    WHERE vc_plan_id IN ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP');
```

Comment: A little bit more info on the error message ? Are LastName and FirstName not null without default value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is exactly what it says it is.  Your last_name column must be defined as not null.  Therefore, you can't insert a null into it.  Since you didn't define what to insert into the column in your insert, it tries to insert null by default and fails.

You must insert something into last name.  I would suggest either a default string or an empty string if you can't get an actual last name to insert.

```
INSERT INTO sysadm.PS_Z_STAGE_TEST_JE (EMPLID, LAST_NAME) 
SELECT DISTINCT(emplid), 'N/A'
FROM ps_vc_plan_mem 
WHERE vc_plan_id IN ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP');
```

Alternatively, you could alter your table so that last_name is nullable.

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious problem that I see with your query is the asterisk at the end:

```
INSERT INTO sysadm.PS_Z_STAGE_TEST_JE(EMPLID) 
    SELECT DISTINCT emplid 
    FROM ps_vc_plan_mem 
    WHERE vc_plan_id IN ('PNC-RS', 'PNC-SO', 'PNC-ESPP');
```

Note that `distinct` is not a function.  It is a modifier on `select`, so the parentheses don't mean anything.

Comment: Hi please see my update.  That asterisk at the end should have been a ;

Answer (score 0):

There is a **asterisk** at the end of your SQL statement.  Please remove and retry.

If [sysadm].[PS_Z_STAGE_TEST_JE] table has a PK, you might want truncate the table before running the statement.